Single collection or multiple collection which one to use in Qdrant vector database?
I am new to Qdrant. Currently, I am planning to store our embeddings in Qdrant (vector database), along with payload which basically contains the language information. Our main goal is to use ANN functionality provided by Qdrant.
Here I want to store last 3 days of embeddings generated by our training pipeline.
Implementation 1:
-Ingest the 3 days of data, without building any global index.
-partition the whole data based on date and language.

perform the ANN with filters based on date and language.

Implementation 2:
-build separate collection based on date. i.e one collection for each date.
-build global indices for each collection.
-Partition the each collection based on languages.
-Perform the ANN with filter based on language.
In implementation 2,  cost and scalability would be the major issues, but i believe global indexing would be better as it offered better recommendation results when compared against KNN ~ 98% matches.
In implementation 1, results have degraded drastically when compared against KNN ~ 50% matches.
Here I am posting the configurations:
{'result': {'status': 'green',
  'optimizer_status': 'ok',
  'vectors_count': 3517432,
  'indexed_vectors_count': 3517432,
  'points_count': 3517432,
  'segments_count': 15,
  'config': {'params': {'vectors': {'size': 128,
     'distance': 'Cosine',
     'hnsw_config': {'m': 0,
      'ef_construct': 200,
      'full_scan_threshold': 10000,
      'on_disk': True,
      'payload_m': 50},
     'on_disk': True},
    'shard_number': 3,
    'replication_factor': 1,
    'write_consistency_factor': 1,
    'on_disk_payload': True},
   'hnsw_config': {'m': 0,
    'ef_construct': 100,
    'full_scan_threshold': 10000,
    'max_indexing_threads': 0,
    'on_disk': False,
    'payload_m': 16},
   'optimizer_config': {'deleted_threshold': 0.2,
    'vacuum_min_vector_number': 1000,
    'default_segment_number': 0,
    'max_segment_size': None,
    'memmap_threshold': None,
    'indexing_threshold': 100,
    'flush_interval_sec': 5,
    'max_optimization_threads': 1},
   'wal_config': {'wal_capacity_mb': 32, 'wal_segments_ahead': 0},
   'quantization_config': None},
  'payload_schema': {'dt': {'data_type': 'keyword', 'points': 3517432},
   'language': {'data_type': 'keyword', 'points': 3517432}}},
 'status': 'ok',
 'time': 0.001034984}


What are the configurational changes that i can make to improve the ANN results in implementation 1 ? Or should i use Implementation 2 ?


I would advocate for the first implementation, although I'm a bit surprised by the numbers. However, that's something that should possibly be improved.
Can you share an example of a query you want to perform? I'd appreciate an example of calling Qdrant APIs with filters applied. I see both payload indexes are of a keyword type, but Qdrant 1.8+ supports datetimes natively:
https://qdrant.tech/documentation/concepts/payload/?q=date#datetime

`url = f"{base_url}/collections/{collection_name}/points/search"
data = {
    "vector": vector,
    "limit": no_of_vecs,
    "with_vectors": with_vectors,
    "with_payload": ["id", "language"],
    'filter':{
    "must": [
        
         { "key": "dt", "match": { "value": dt } },  
        { "key": "language", "match": { "value": lang } }
    ]
    }
    ,
    "params": params
}


resp = req.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))

`

Date in payload is string, not typical datetime object.

Actually, Qdrant interprets strings as datetime objects. If your strings are of a "2023-02-08T10:49:00Z" format, I'd still try to use them. Nevertheless, I'll try to reproduce the example and see if I can also notice reduced search precision.

Adding a sample payload for your reference :'payload': {'id': '20240331_28',
'language': 'hindi',
'pid': 'XXXXXXX',
'dt': '20240331',
'primary_artists_id': ['XXXXX', 'XXXX']}
here dt refers to date
